# cljc file not hot reloading for clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I recently implemented my first ".cljc" file that is supposed to bridge between clojure and clojurescript.
All went well, also figwheel is picking up the changes and nicely refreshes the new code, however in the clojure side the file is not hot-reloaded.

I'm using the usual

```
[ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
```

in my development middleware.

In my `project.clj`, I have:

```
 :source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljc"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I have kind of figured this out, it's something related to plumatic's `schema` defs I have there. I separated into multiple `cljc` files, apparently the `defschema` is having trouble in some cases reloading in `clj`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that source paths for both .clj and .cljc files are set at the top level in `project.clj` for the JVM compilation:

```
:source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljc"]
```

And for the ClojureScript side, ensure that source paths are set anywhere that you have compilation directives for Figwheel e.g.:

```
; this might be your from your dev profile cljs config:

   :cljsbuild
   {:builds
    {:app
     {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "env/dev/cljs"]
      :compiler
      {:main "my-project.app"
       :asset-path "/js/out"
       :output-to "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js"
       :output-dir "target/cljsbuild/public/js/out"
       :source-map true
       :optimizations :none
       :pretty-print true}}}}
```

Sounds like your Figwheel config is good, though.